# Using JavaCompiler API in a Spring Boot app - unable to properly set the compilation classpath

Tags: spring-boot, java-compiler-api

We have an app that's been migrated from a traditional WAR Spring web application to what we had hoped would be a modern Spring Boot executable Jar.

One of the app modules uses the `JavaCompiler` API to generate Java code and compile it in runtime.
The generated code requires dependencies that reside in the web app classpath, and so we had roughly the following code:

```java
StandardJavaFileManager standardFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // set compiler's classpath to be same as the runtime's
    String classpathString = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-nowarn",
                                    "-classpath",
                                    classpathString,
                                    "-g",
                                    "-source",
                                    javaVersion,
                                    "-target",
                                    javaVersion));

    Collection classpathFiles = getClasspathJars(classpathString);
    addPreviousCompiledClassesToClasspathFiles(rootClassPath, classpathFiles);

    try {
        File file = new File(getTargetRoot(tempClassPath));
        file.mkdirs();
        standardFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Lists.newArrayList(file));
        standardFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, classpathFiles);

        // adding current dir to the source path, to find the compiled DV
        if (generateSeparateJarsForEachDecision.equals(NO_JAR)) {
            standardFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, Lists.newArrayList(file));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


        List<CharSequenceJavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Lists
                .newArrayList(new CharSequenceJavaFileObject(   StringUtils.capitalize(filename),
                                                                toString(javaCode)));
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler
                .getTask(writer, standardFileManager, listener, optionList, null, compilationUnits);
        status = task.call();
```

```

However, that doesn't work with Boot.
The classpath only contains `my-app.jar`, and I can't add any of the nested jars to the `-cp` of the task - it just won't those nested jars.
I've also attempted to manually add the to the `-cp` parameter them like so: `{absolute-path}/my-app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/my-dep.jar`
`{absolute-path}/my-app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/*.jar`

None of those worked.
Thought about using the `<requiresUnpack>` tag on build too, but that didn't seem to help because I couldn't get a hold of the expanded dir in order to add it to the classpath.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution here? I'm faced with the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue.

Looks like a limitation with spring boot.

So created a standalone application with Jersey and Tomcat embedded.

Now jar contains all libraries and able to set it as class path to Java Compiler